# How can I add a Hashtable as an object in another hashtable Option Strict On is set?

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I'm trying to create an object in VB.net that contains a set of key/value pairs, the values of which  could be strings, ints, or other objects containing key/value pairs.

The following code runs as I would expect; I can add key/values to the hashtable, including another hashtable that I can also add key/values to.  I can also read the values out of the object.

```
Dim ht As Hashtable = New Hashtable

    ht.Add("Item1", "Item1 Description")
    ht.Add("Item2", 42)

    ht.Add("Item3", New Hashtable)
    ht.Item("Item3").Add("Item3a", "Item3a Description")
    ht.Item("Item3").Add("Item3b", "Item3b Description")

    Console.WriteLine(ht.Item("Item3")("Item3b"))
```

However, this only works if 'Option Strict' is not set.  Adding `Option Strict On` gives me an error: "BC30574  Option Strict On disallows late binding".

My question is, 'How can I set a hashtable as a value inside another hashtable when Option Strict On is set?'

I'm open to using collections other than a hashtable if it's that choice that's causing the issue. I don't have the options of setting Option Strict Off, as this is for an 'invoke code' block of a Ui Path workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Hashtable is a particularly ancient data storage container; why are you using it? ("this is for an 'invoke code' block of a Ui Path workflow" doesn't mean much to me)

Comment: DirectCast(ht("Item3), HashTable).Add(...)

Comment: How about using a `Dictionary`?

Comment: The `Hashtable` class effectively became obsolete in 2005. Just as we all started using `List(Of T)` instead of `ArrayList`, so we also started using `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` instead of `Hashtable`. In your case, if your keys are all type `String` and you values are different types then you should be using a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`. Note that that doesn't solve your problem because you still get values as `Object` references. It's just good practice in this decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different ways as code below shows:

```
    Dim ht As Hashtable = New Hashtable

    ht.Add("Item1", "Item1 Description")
    ht.Add("Item2", 42)

    ht.Add("Item3", New Hashtable From {{"Item3_1", "Item3_1 Description"},
                                        {"Item3_2", "Item3_3 Description"},
                                        {"Item3_3", "Item3_3 Description"}})


    CType(ht.Item("Item3"), Hashtable).Add("Item3_4", "Item3_4 Description")
    CType(ht.Item("Item3"), Hashtable).Item("Item3_1") = "Another description for Item3_1"

    ht.Add("Item4", New List(Of String) From {"Element1", "Element2"})
```

Comment: I've updated my test code using CType as shown by G3nt_M3caj, and DirectCast as mentioned by @Hans Passant, and both work.  (I just have some reading to do now to properly understand CType and DirectCast, and the uses of each of them...)  Thanks!

Comment: CType is a general type converter and have a vast use as doesn’t need types is the same in a conversion (obviosly you cannot convert an Integer to an Image). Directcast is more strict as needs target to be the same/descendant or extended of the type which you are going to convert. Is a bit more faster than Ctype but throws exception when  the type is not correspondent. You also can use TryCast (is like Directcast) which doesn’t throws exception if the type missed. At this point you can only test the returned Type if is nothing.Where you are sure the types are the same I suggest DirectCast.

Comment: Are you always going to know for sure that the value you are getting will be a `Hashtable`? The fact that you have different types in the values could mean that you won't know know what type you're getting back for a particular key until you get it. In that case, it's actually `TryCast` that you should be using, which would mean restructuring your code a bit.